# Regular Expression and embedded special characters

Tags: regex, vba

I'm using VBScript and have a string that I'm reading from a file, an example would be "ab$cd\ef".

I use a regular expression to Replace "c" with "xyz". That works fine.

But the replacement Pattern is input by the user - and they may decide they want to replace "b$" with "xyz". The problem is that "b$" means "Find a 'b' character at the end of the string".

So I need to be able to run a *priming* regular expression on the user input to Replace "$" with "\$" to make the pattern into "b\$"

My **Pattern** for this pre-regexp would need to be "$", and the command:

manPattern=Regexp.Replace(UserInput,"\$")

But of course, "$" means "end-of-string". I hope you can see the problem.

Is there a way round this? I could manually edit the string by doing a byte-by-byte search - but that seems a bit unnecessary when we have Regular Expressions to do the work for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the user string first. Use the following code:

```
Dim regExEscape As New RegExp
With regExEscape
    .pattern = "[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
End With
```

And when defining the regex using the user-defined subpattern use

```
.pattern = regExEscape.Replace(user_string, "\$&")
```

The `[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]` pattern contains a single character class that matches all possible metacharacters that you need to escape in a pattern to be treated as a literal character.  It matches `-`, `\`, `^`, `$`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `.`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, and when you replace it with `\$&`, an escaping `\` is added right before them (the `$&` is a backreference to the whole match value).

Comment: stribizew That worked - but I have no idea  why - can you explain please?

Comment: I must rush now... I will try to add some short explanation now. Let me know if there is anything unlcear, I will try to update later.

Comment: That makes sense @Wiktor - thank you very much for your help!