# Find replace on the entire string fragments between delimiters VBA

Tags: excel, regex, vba, replace, office365

I have pipe-delimited strings I need to find and replace on the `entire` substring between the pipes

So if my strings looks like

`AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|000`  or `AAA|AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|000` Or `AAA|AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|AAA`

The `AAA` can be anywhere in the string. beginning and/or end or exist multiple times

and I want to replace `AAA` with `ZZZ`

The result I need:

`AAAP|AAA TTT|ZZZ|000` or `ZZZ|AAAP|AAA TTT|ZZZ|000` or `ZZZ|AAAP|AAA TTT|ZZZ|ZZZ`

The result I am getting

`AAAP|ZZZ TTT|ZZZ|000` ...

How to restrict the replacement to the entire substring

```
Sub ExtractSubstringReplace()
Dim strSource, strReplace, strFind, RegExpReplaceWord, r, a

    strSource = "AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|000"
    strFind = "AAA"
    strReplace = "ZZZ"
  
    Dim re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Global = True
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.Pattern = "\b" & strFind & "\b"
    RegExpReplaceWord = re.Replace(strSource, strReplace)
  
  MsgBox RegExpReplaceWord
  
End Sub
```

Comment: What about cases like `AAA|AAA TTT|AAA|000` and `AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|AAA` Can the text be in the begining and in the end? If not, then look for `|AAA|` and then replace.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace only those strings that are flanked by pikes?

Comment: Yes, `AAA` can be anywhere in the string. beginning and/or end. I will update my question. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: I am out at the moment so can't test this. Can you try the pattern `"^" & strFind & "(?=\|)|(?<=\|)" & strFind & "(?=\|)|(?<=\|)" & strFind & "$"`

Comment: I get `Application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: Just tested `^AAA(?=\|)|(?<=\|)AAA(?=\|)|(?<=\|)AAA$` in https://regexr.com/3hmb6 and it seems to be working

Comment: @SiddharthRout VBA regex uses ECMAScript 5, it does not support lookbehinds. See [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67708227/3832970) below that does not require lookbehinds.

Comment: I am not at the pc. Will have a look in sometime. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```vb
re.Pattern = "(^|\|)" & strFind & "(?![^|])"
RegExpReplaceWord = re.Replace(strSource, "$1" & strReplace)
```

See the `(^|\|)AAA(?![^|])` [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dA7p3j/1). Note it is equal to `(^|\|)AAA(?=\||$)`.

*Details*:

- `(^|\|)` - Capturing group 1: either start of string or a pipe char
- `AAA` - search string
- `(?![^|])` / `(?=\||$)` - a lookahead that makes sure there is either `|` or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

**NOTE**: if your `strFind` can contain special regex metacharacters, make sure you escape the string using the solution from [Regular Expression and embedded special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766531).

Comment: Thank you works great, also thanks for the explanation and the link

Answer (score 4):

Put the string on which replacement is to be made (AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|000) in cell A1 of Sheet1 and run the following code.
You will get the whole string with replacements made in cell A2.

```
Sub ExtractSubstringReplace()
    Dim strArr, str, strArrNew(), strSource As String, strReplace As String, strFind As String, i As Long
    
    strSource = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
    strFind = "AAA"
    strReplace = "ZZZ"
    
    strArr = Split(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value, "|")
    
    For Each str In strArr
        If str = strFind Then str = strReplace
        ReDim Preserve strArrNew(i)
        strArrNew(i) = str
        i = i + 1
    Next str
    
    For Each str In strArrNew
        Debug.Print str
    Next str
    
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = Join(strArrNew, "|")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, very nice approch

Answer (score 4):

I would go with the option presented in the comments by @Siddharth Rout as it is probably the most efficient.

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox ExtractSubstringReplace("AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|000", "AAA", "ZZZ")
    MsgBox ExtractSubstringReplace("AAA|AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|000", "AAA", "ZZZ")
    MsgBox ExtractSubstringReplace("AAA|AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|AAA", "AAA", "ZZZ")
End Sub


Public Function ExtractSubstringReplace(ByVal strSource As String _
                                      , ByVal strFind As String _
                                      , ByVal strReplace As String _
                                      , Optional ByVal delimiter As String = "|" _
) As String
    Dim result As String
    
    'Duplicate delimiter and also add leading and trailing delimiter
    result = delimiter & Replace(strSource, delimiter, delimiter & delimiter) & delimiter
    'Replace substrings
    result = Replace(result, delimiter & strFind & delimiter, delimiter & strReplace & delimiter)
    'Remove leading and trailing delimiter that we added previously
    result = Mid$(result, Len(delimiter) + 1, Len(result) - Len(delimiter) * 2)
    'Restore delimiters
    ExtractSubstringReplace = Replace(result, delimiter & delimiter, delimiter)
End Function
```

You can also use the function in an Excel cell.

Comment: Christian, thanks for a nice approach! I now have three unique ways of doing this

Comment: @xyz333 No problem. Remember that RegEx is about 300 times slower than the other 2 solutions. Here is a [speed test](https://gist.github.com/cristianbuse/a646897aad038970ab0dd5b2cebd90f4). Just run the ```TestSpeed``` method. If you want to compare just my solution with the Split/Join (refactored without ranges) then you will need to comment out the middle section (the regEx) and increase the value of the ```iterations``` constant to something like a million to actually see a difference.

Comment: @xyz333 Just edited the gist and added a 4th method which is the Split/Join solution but optimized. This one is even faster than my solution.

Comment: Thank you, that was all very informative and helpful to know

Comment: @CristianBuse Nice & helpful for any user by your speed test addition :+) Fyi posted another fast approach with slightly shortened code based on the same ideas.

Answer (score 2):

**Slightly shortened code**

As addition to @ChristianBuse 's fine solution another *fast* approach based on the same idea *(needing only 0.00 to max. 0.02 seconds)*:

```
Function SubRep(src, fnd, repl, Optional ByVal delim As String = "|") As String
    SubRep = delim & src & delim
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 2
        SubRep = Replace(SubRep, delim & fnd & delim, delim & repl & delim)
    Next
    SubRep = Mid$(SubRep, 2, Len(SubRep) - 2)
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim terms
    terms = Array("AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|000", "AAA|AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|000", "AAA|AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|AAA")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(terms) To UBound(terms)
        Debug.Print Format(i, "0 ") & terms(i) & vbNewLine & "  " & _
            SubRep(terms(i), "AAA", "ZZZ")
    Next
End Sub
```

*Results in VB Editor's immediate window*

```
0 AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|000
  AAAP|AAA TTT|ZZZ|000
1 AAA|AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|000
  ZZZ|AAAP|AAA TTT|ZZZ|000
2 AAA|AAAP|AAA TTT|AAA|AAA
  ZZZ|AAAP|AAA TTT|ZZZ|ZZZ
```

Comment: Nice. It's faster because you are only doing 2 replacements instead of 3 like I did. Did not occur to me to run it twice. I would still change ```SubRep = Mid$(SubRep, 2, Len(SubRep) - 2)``` to ```SubRep = Mid$(SubRep, Len(delim) + 1, Len(SubRep) - Len(delim) * 2)``` just in case the delimiter has multiple characters. In terms of speed it's only slightly slower than the optimized Join/Split but only about 100ms for 100000 loops. +1